# Laravel 5 Cashier - is there a way to grab all the plans that exist in stripe

Tags: php, laravel

I was looking through the laravel 5 documentation for cashier and i don't see any option to grab the plans that i have in stripe. Is there an undocumented way? or do i have to manually add the options to a select dropdown?